# Alert firing with undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am using jquery dialog to submit a form to a db and what I would like to do, is, on the beforeclose function, fire an alert to show what they submiited. Problem, is that I am getting 'box' undefined in firebug. I assumed that the variables would work in my code, but obviously not. I would be grateful if someone could check my code to see where I made the error. I shall only post the code thats relevant. Thanks

```
beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
                jAlert("You have successfully editted\n\rBox: "+box+"\n\r"+
                           "Status: "+status+"\n\r"+
                           "Size: "+size+"\n\r", 'Box addittion successfull');
                $("#f2").html("");
            }
```

The .click part

```
$('#EB_submit').click(function () {

            var submit = $('#EB_submit').val();
            var status = $('#EB_status').val();
            var id = $('#EB_id').val();
            var box = $('#EB_custref').val();
            var size = $('#EB_size').val();
            var service = $('#EB_service :selected').text();
            var address = $('#EB_address :selected').text();
            var data = 'submit=' + submit +
                       '&id=' + id +
                       '&status=' + status +
                       '&box=' + box +
                       '&size=' + size;
```

Comment: Where are you using the `beforeclose:` call? Could you post some more code?

Comment: @dogbert. The beforeclose is part of the dialog options and in this case, is used before the .click event. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you posted, the var 'box' is local to the click function and unavailable to the dialog function.

```
var box;

$('#EB_submit').click(function () {

        var submit = $('#EB_submit').val();
        var status = $('#EB_status').val();
        var id = $('#EB_id').val();
        box = $('#EB_custref').val();
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwUjv/

Comment: See the code I posted in my answer. Declare box above the click function and the dialog function.

Comment: I am now getting the alert, but with undefined instead of the value. This is how I am using: var box;
        var status;
        var size; above the .click event. Thanks

Comment: Where is the dialog box called and where are the values be set?

Comment: There is quite a lot of code so I have placed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/M7R4K/

Comment: The values are to be set in the alert in the beforeclose function as I posted.

Comment: Way too much going on with your code so I added a fiddle to my answer.

Comment: Thank you jen. I am still struggling with this but thanks to your code, I shall go over all my code again to try and follow the logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

box is not defined in the beforeclose function.  define box as a global variable.